ui-select not displaying selected value
I am using AngularJS with ui-select to create a dropdown for selecting a holding time period. The dropdown populates correctly and displays the options, but after I perform a search action and select an option, the selected value is not displayed in the input field.
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-5">
    <label class="control-label"><strong>Holding Time Period : 
      </strong></label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-7">
    <!--<select name="procurementMode" ui-select2="dropDown" ng-model="search.HoldingTimePeriodId" data-placeholder="Select Holding Time Period" title="Select Holding Time Period">
    <option></option>
    <option ng-repeat="t in holdingTimePeriods" value="{{t.Id}}">{{t.Display}}</option>
    </select>-->
    <ui-select name="procurementMode" ng-model="search.HoldingTimePeriodId" theme="select2" style="width: 100% !important;">
      <ui-select-match allow-clear="true" placeholder="Select Holding Time Period" title="Select Holding Time Period">{{$select.selected.Display}}</ui-select-match>
      <ui-select-choices refresh-delay="1" repeat="t.Id as t in holdingTimePeriods | filter:$select.search">
      {{t.Display}}
      </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
  </div>
</div>

holdingTimePeriod.png
JavaScript File
(function (window, angular, undefined) {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('angularModule.controllers').controller('searchempManagerCtrl', ['$scope', '$compile', '$window', 'ajaxCall', '$controller', 'checkPermissions', '$rootScope', 'permissionCheckService', 'emailManagerColumns', '$timeout', function ($scope, $compile, $window, ajaxCall, $controller, checkPermissions, $rootScope, permissionCheckService, emailManagerColumns, $timeout) {
        permissionCheckService.check('Email_Manager_View');
        //Injecting common useful values to the scope
        $controller('commonCtrl', { $scope: $scope });

        $scope.fromdate = "";
        $scope.enable = false;
        $scope.templateId = { Id: null };
        $scope.search = { OpeningStockSubmitted: null, DisclosureSubmitted: null, AnnualHoldingSubmitted: null, HoldingTimePeriodId: null, QuarterlyIntimationSubmitted: null, CompanyId: null, ClassId: null };
        
        $scope.gridConfig.getData = function (e) {

            $scope.search.RowsPerPage = $scope.reset ? 20 : e.data.pageSize;
            $scope.search.PageNumber = $scope.reset ? 1 : e.data.page;
            if (!isValidObject($scope.search.AsOfDateString)) {
                alertify.error("Please Select As Of Date");
                return;
            }
            $scope.search.HoldingTimePeriodId = $scope.search.HoldingTimePeriodId ? $scope.search.HoldingTimePeriodId.toString() : null;
            $scope.search.QuarterlyIntimationTimePeriodId = $scope.search.QuarterlyIntimationTimePeriodId ? $scope.search.QuarterlyIntimationTimePeriodId.toString() : null;
            $scope.search.CompanyId = $scope.search.CompanyId ? $scope.search.CompanyId.toString() : null;
            $scope.search.ClassId = $scope.search.ClassId ? $scope.search.ClassId.toString() : null;
            //$scope.search.HoldingTimePeriodId = $scope.search.HoldingTimePeriodId.toString();
            //$scope.search.QuarterlyIntimationTimePeriodId = $scope.search.QuarterlyIntimationTimePeriodId.toString();
            //$scope.search.CompanyId = $scope.search.CompanyId.toString();
            //$scope.search.ClassId = $scope.search.ClassId.toString();
            $rootScope.viewLoading = true;
            $scope.gridConfig.isLocalData = true;
            ajaxCall.post('/ETT/EmailManager/SearchEmployees', JSON.stringify({ emailManager: $scope.search }), false).then(function (data) {
                if (data.IsError) {
                    alertify.error(data.Message);
                    $rootScope.viewLoading = false;
                    return;
                }
                $scope.gridConfig.ds = $scope.formatData(data.SearchResults);
                $scope.gridConfig.dataCount = data.Count;
                $scope.count = data.Count;
                e.success({ data: $scope.gridConfig.ds, total: $scope.gridConfig.dataCount });
                $rootScope.viewLoading = false;
            });

        };
        $scope.getHoldingTimePeriodList = function () {
            ajaxCall.get('/TimePeriod/GetAllHoldingTimePeriods').then(function (data) {
                if (!isValidObject(data)) {
                    return;
                } else {
                    if (data.IsError) {
                        alertify.error(data.Message);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Holding Time Periods:', data.holdingTimePeriods);
                        $scope.holdingTimePeriods = data.holdingTimePeriods;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        

        $scope.exportAllRecords = function (isExportAll) {
            $rootScope.viewLoading = true;
            if (!isExportAll) {
                getExportData_Kendo_GetFile(false, $scope.gridConfig.gridId, $scope.gridConfig.columns, undefined, undefined, undefined, true);
            }
            else {
                xhr_DownloadFile('/ETT/EmailManager/ExportToExcel?asOfDate=' + $scope.search.AsOfDateString + '&joiningDateTo=' + $scope.search.JoiningDateToString + '&joiningDateFrom=' + $scope.search.JoiningDateFromString + '&relievingDateAsOf=' + $scope.search.RelievingDateAsOfString + '&excludeRelieved=' + $scope.search.ExcludeRelieved + '&openingStockSubmitted=' + $scope.search.OpeningStockSubmitted + '&disclosureSubmitted=' +
                    $scope.search.DisclosureSubmitted + '&annualHoldingSubmitted=' + $scope.search.AnnualHoldingSubmitted + '&holdingTimePeriodId=' + $scope.search.HoldingTimePeriodId.toString() + '&quarterlyIntimationSubmitted=' + $scope.search.QuarterlyIntimationSubmitted + '&quarterlyIntimationTimePeriodId=' + $scope.search.QuarterlyIntimationTimePeriodId.toString() + '&companyId=' + $scope.search.CompanyId.toString() + '&classId=' + $scope.search.ClassId.toString(), 'GET');
            }
            $rootScope.viewLoading = false;
        }
        
        

    }]);
})(window, window.angular);

Expected Behavior:
After selecting an option, the selected value should be displayed in the ui-select input field.
Actual Behavior:
The selected value is not displayed in the ui-select input field after selection.

Please share a simple example highlighting the issue on stack overflow code editor for checking, there is too much code, only minimal reproducible code needed

Hi Abhishek.  Wondering if you saw my answer below?

@Gerald LeRoy the solution is not working

It's possible that ui-select and ng-model exist in/on different scopes.
You might try this..
ng-model="$parent.search.HoldingTimePeriodId"

If that doesn't work, other options to try are listed here.
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/FAQs
